# AORUS Onboard SoundCard no listed

Tags: drivers, soundcard

My AORUS Motherboard onboard soundcard is not listed.

Ubuntu:

```
$ lsb_release -a | grep Description
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
```

Kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux laura 5.4.0-72-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:35:00 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MotherBoard:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 2 | grep "Manufacturer\|Product"
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: B365 M AORUS ELITE-CF
```

Only my NVIDIA GPU card is listed

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Nvidia GPU 51 HDMI/DP
```

The card isn't listed by lspci either:

```
$ lspci -v | grep Audio
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
```

Any suggestions on what should I do?

Comment: I feel dumb, the Audio Card was disabled in the bios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem and followed

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

And this just solved my problem:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1344029/1261990

Hopefully works for you too.

Comment: As I had to reboot my pc, I checked the bios and the Audio Chipset was disabled.
That step was listed in the SoundTroubleShootingProcedure you linked to. Thanks.