# Internal sound card not detected

Tags: 18.04, sound, soundcard

In my Ubuntu 18.04 sound setting I have only  `Radeon RX 580` as available option. So the PC outputs no sound, though I can get sound from TV output, but I'd like to get sound directly from the PC to my headphone jack.

Here are some more info:

```
pc@media:~$ sudo lshw -c sound 
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:fcf60000-fcf63fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.3
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.3
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:fce00000-fce07fff
```

I have many tricks that I found like reinstalling pulseaudio but none worked. So appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last:  the official Ubuntu troubleshooting guide came to resque:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Followed all steps meticulously but only after editing  `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and adding

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

And reboot, `Line out` appeared in the sound setting options window and the sound is there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after updating the system, a similar error occurred with the lack of drivers for the sound.

The solution was to install the package:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-55-generic
```

and reboot

To verify which version you need to install, type: `cat /proc/version`

> Linux version 5.8.0-55-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-050) (gcc (Ubuntu
> 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 2 08:55:04 UTC 2021

You can also try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```